# Помогите слова на слоги по теории Бондарко

Tags: фонетика

Может быть так?

Се-стра, у-тро, балк-он, космо-навт, ар-хите-ктура, обо-йма, июльс-кий, отчи-таться, эска-дра, лестни-чный, байдар-ка, се-мья, мену-эт, праз-дник,майс-кий, контро-льная.

Comment: А знаки препинания в заголовке отсутствуют по какой теории?